# get file content type for uploaded file

Tags: php

I am trying to grab information for a uploaded file including file content type but I came to know that `$_FILES["uploaded_files"]["type"]` is not reliable.
Also I heard mime_content_type is deprecated, finfo PCL extension needs to be installed.

```
$fileData = file_get_contents ($_FILES["uploaded_files"]["tmp_name"]);
$fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_files"]["name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_files"]["type"];
```

I am not sure which one is more reliable. Could you please shed some light on this topic? I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If file info so important for you, you can use this library http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ for getting info about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `$_FILES["uploaded_files"]["type"]` is not reliable, Anywhere what about using `getimagesize`.
Read the return value of this function from following doc, It may help you:-

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php